# @Transactional in Lambda Expressions

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, java-8, spring-data

I use @transactional for DB update operations in normal functions.But in lambda expression @transactional in not allowed. How to handle this ? below is my code.

```
//normal function
  @Transactional
   void saveTransaction(String uniqueId) {
       Transaction transaction = new Transaction();
       transaction.setUniqueId(uniqueId);
       transactionRepository.save(transaction);
   }

   **@Transactional**  //Error Message - @Transactional not applicable to this field
   Consumer<String> saveTransaction = (uniqueId) ->
   {
       Transaction transaction = new Transaction();
       transaction.setUniqueId(uniqueId);
       transactionRepository.save(transaction);
   };
```

Comment: make your lambda call the transactional method or use manual transaction managment. Generally multiline lambda's are a code smell.

Comment: Yes, you can't annotate a variable with this, look at its supported element type: method and type. What is the reason you want to do this? What to you actually get from making a "transactional lambda"?

Answer (score 4):

You may use the [Programmatic transaction management](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-programmatic) aproach.

> The Spring Framework provides two means of programmatic transaction
> management:
>
> - Using the `TransactionTemplate`.
> - Using a `PlatformTransactionManager` implementation directly.
>
> The Spring team generally recommends the `TransactionTemplate` for
> programmatic transaction management. The second approach is similar to
> using the JTA `UserTransaction` API, although exception handling is
> less cumbersome.

Firstly inject the `TransactionTemplate` reference in your bean.

```java
  // single TransactionTemplate shared amongst all methods in this instance
  private final TransactionTemplate transactionTemplate;
```

**Option 1**

Initialize your `Consumer<String>` attribute within an initializer method annotated with `@PostConstruct`

```java
        @PostConstruct
        public void init() {
            saveTransaction = (uniqueId) -> transactionTemplate.execute(new TransactionCallbackWithoutResult() {
                protected void doInTransactionWithoutResult(TransactionStatus status) {
                      Transaction transaction = new Transaction();
                      transaction.setUniqueId(uniqueId);
                      transactionRepository.save(transaction);
                }
            });
        }
```

**Option 2**

Initialize `Consumer<String>` attribute within constructor

```java
private final TransactionTemplate transactionTemplate;
private final Consumer<String> saveTransaction;

YourService(TransactionTemplate transactionTemplate) {
    this.transactionTemplate = transactionTemplate;
    saveTransaction = (uniqueId) -> transactionTemplate.execute(new TransactionCallbackWithoutResult() {
             protected void doInTransactionWithoutResult(TransactionStatus status) {
                      Transaction transaction = new Transaction();
                      transaction.setUniqueId(uniqueId);
                      transactionRepository.save(transaction);
                }
            });
}
```

According to Spring Docs:

> Programmatic transaction management is usually a good idea only if you
> have a small number of transactional operations. For example, if you
> have a web application that require transactions only for certain
> update operations, you may not want to set up transactional proxies
> using Spring or any other technology. In this case, using the
> TransactionTemplate may be a good approach. Being able to set the
> transaction name explicitly is also something that can only be done
> using the programmatic approach to transaction management.

Answer (score 1):

@Transactional can be used with public functions only not on the variables. Lambda is not the function declaration. It is like variable declaration.

Answer (score 0):

`@Transactional` only applicable to methods. Your `saveTransaction` is field.

To achieve desired behavior you need:

- Declare public method and put your code in it.
- Initialize you field with reference to that method. Keep in mind that by default spring use proxy to implement `@Transactional`, so `this.myMethod` won't work.